# Is hamiltonian graph a graph where a Cycle covers all the vertexes?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I learnt that , a Cycle should have unique vertices and unique edges where start  vertex =  end vertex.

So if the there is a Cycle that can cover every vertex, is that sufficient enough to make the graph HAMILTONIAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, by definition Hamiltonian cycle is a cycle that traverses all the vertices.

Comment: does the same imply for euler graph? i.e. is a euler graph ,  a graph with a cycle which covers all the edges?

Comment: @ShivaShankari Can you be more clear? If you meant "If G has a cycle that traverses every vertex then G is Eulerian" then this is false

Comment: If G has a closed trail that traverses every VERTEX, then G is Eulerian. is that right?

Comment: No, it's false. Take $K_4$. It obviously has a closed trail that traverses every vertex $C_4$, but it's not Eulerian

Comment: what is the condition for a graph to be eulerian then?

Comment: There has to be a circuit that traverses each edge exactly once. Such a circuit exists if and only iff each vertex in the graph has even degree